# Deleting a node in a linked list with void return statement [Java]

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to a do an assignment to delete a node in a Linked list. I have the front node deletion to work, and to return when the friendList is null. firstFriend is a Friend object that has a Person in memory and points to another friend. This method removes a friend from the firstFriend linked list. I'm struggling with how to update firstFriend properly within the method

```
public void removeFriend(Person friend){        
    Friend prev = null, curr = firstFriend, front = firstFriend;
    if (curr == null){
        return;
    }
    while(firstFriend != null){
        if(friend.equals(curr.who)){ 
            if(prev == null){
                firstFriend = firstFriend.nextFriend;
            return;
        }
            else{
                prev = curr.nextFriend;
        }
        prev = curr;        
        curr = curr.nextFriend;

    }       
        firstFriend = front;

    return; // replace this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint #1: you only ever need to update `firstFriend` when you are deleting the first `Friend` on the list

Hint #2: separate the problem of removing a `Friend` into the two parts of 1) finding the `Friend` node that points to the `Person` you want to remove and 2) actually removing the `Friend`, instead of trying to do everything at once.